# Mule Maven Deployment Failure 401-Unauthorized

Tags: maven, mule, mulesoft

Trying to deploy to our AWS VM Instances (havng mule runtimes 3.8.5). Our Jenkins Job has triggered the deployment and getting 401 Unauthorized. Verified the creds are working fine and no special characters. Not sure what else could be wrong. Can someone suggest me from below logs.

One other doubt is the does the aws region causes an issue ? ( the instances running on west but on jenkins build job its showing east)

```
 Failed: 401 Unauthorized: Unauthorized
[ERROR] Failed to deploy XXXX: Failed to deploy application XXXX
org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy application XXX
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.arm.ArmDeployer.deploy(ArmDeployer.java:55)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.DeployMojo.deployWithDeployer(DeployMojo.java:194)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.DeployMojo.arm(DeployMojo.java:177)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.DeployMojo.doExecute(DeployMojo.java:154)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.AbstractMuleMojo.execute(AbstractMuleMojo.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.ApiException: 401 Unauthorized: Unauthorized
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.AbstractMuleApi.validateStatusSuccess(AbstractMuleApi.java:78)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.AbstractMuleApi.getBearerToken(AbstractMuleApi.java:69)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.AbstractMuleApi.init(AbstractMuleApi.java:60)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.plugin.mule.arm.ArmDeployer.deploy(ArmDeployer.java:38)
```

Comment: What is the version of the mule maven plugin?  Was it working previously?

Comment: mule-maven-plugin:2.2.1 , yes it was working previously

Comment: Version 2.2.1 is three years old... upgrade ...

Comment: yes, planning to upgrade in 2021 . But for now it says 401 and when i tried -X it doesnt give much details (just saying 401)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick answer

401 means : The HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

So, possible causes are:

- incorrect credentials
- jenkins incorrect credentials injection or jenkins bug
- **mule-maven-plugin:2.2.1** bug

#### Validate credentials

Jenkins or mule-maven-plugin bug are not common. Human error is very common.

In order to validate who is causing the error?, I advice you validate your credentials **directly to Anypoint http url**

#### Anypoint login url

Reviewing the plugin official source code **v2.2.1** related to your stacktrace `ArmDeployer.deploy(ArmDeployer.java:38)` :

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-maven-plugin/tree/v2.2.1

And its classes (in this order):

- [ArmApiTestCase.java](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-maven-plugin/blob/v2.2.1/src/test/java/org/mule/tools/maven/plugin/mule/ArmApiTestCase.java)
- [ArmDeployer.java](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-maven-plugin/blob/v2.2.1/src/main/java/org/mule/tools/maven/plugin/mule/arm/ArmDeployer.java)
- [ArmApi.java](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-maven-plugin/blob/v2.2.1/src/main/java/org/mule/tools/maven/plugin/mule/arm/ArmApi.java)
- [AbstractMuleApi.java](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-maven-plugin/blob/v2.2.1/src/main/java/org/mule/tools/maven/plugin/mule/AbstractMuleApi.java)

I got the base url:

```
ArmApi(null, "https://anypoint.mulesoft.com", USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENVIRONMENT, "", false);
```

And with this url, I found this authentication request snippet:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"jane","password":"doe"}' https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login
```

Also in this web , another ways to authentication are showed:

- form params
- bearer(used for mule-maven-plugin:2.2.1)

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-generate-your-Authorization-Bearer-token-for-Anypoint-Platform

#### Direct authentication: success

If `https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login` returns you a **successful answer**, will indicate that there are some error at credentials manager in your jenkins or just an error in the human jenkins admin.

#### Direct authentication: failure

If `https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login` returns you an **error answer** like your **401 Unauthorized**, will indicate that mule-maven-plugin:2.2.1 and jenkins **are good**, and your credentials **are wrong!!!** or maybe they expired.

Anyway just to try, reset the credentials or ask for a new user/password.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing this. I did tried with creds and its giving unauthorized error via curl. But we are using Okta for sign-in to mulesoft. so i guess we should use bearer method (first get saml response and then get token). 

I got the saml response but not sure how to proceed after that

Comment: I saw the Bearer token in some classes of **mule-maven-plugin v2.2.1**, so I think you can review if it is possible to use bearer instead user/password. Also you could try with a more recent version of this plugin. In another way, I think okta is for interactive login for human users. But for non-interactive users (background process like jenkins) I think  mule-maven-plugin requires user/password or some kind of long lived api-key

Comment: created a new account in anypoint platform without MFA( no single sig on ) and used the creds in settings.xml , It started working.

Comment: Glad I helped find the problem.